# Contact list separation on Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am designing contact list which is ordered in alphabetic order.

```
<li class="btn-default" ng-repeat="user in users | filter:userFilter  | orderBy: 'name'" ng-click="selectUser(user)">
  <div class="userPhoto"><img src="images/users/{{user.photo}}" /></div>
  <div class="userDetails">
    <div class="userName">{{user.name}}</div>
    <div class="userPosition">{{user.cellPhone}}</div>
  </div>
  <span ng-show=" ! $last ">-</span>
</li>
```

It is showing

```
a
a1
b
c
d
.
.
z
```

I want this details shown as

```
a
a1
----
b
----
c
----
.
.
```

For every starting of alphabetic order, I need one border and First letter of that word shown in Top.

It will be like Android Phone Contact List

Answer (score 0):

You could add this function to your controller:

```
$scope.isNewLetter = function(index) {
      if(index+1 == self.data.length)
          return false;
      var x = self.data[index].name[0],
          y = self.data[index+1].name[0];
      return (x!== y);
};
```

What it does it basically that if the first letter in the name of the next person in the data list is not the same as the current one, it returns true.

Then call in your divider element

```
<span ng-show="isNewLetter($index)">-</span>
```

I have a [working example](http://jsbin.com/cidiweqido/2/) which you can take a look at.